# Subreports do not show any data while making pdf from Java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

Problem 1. *JasperReports* subreports do not show any data while making pdf from *Java* code. But when I preview by *iReport* it gives correct data in main report as well as subreports. I am using xml data source.

Have done :

1. Change path of subreport by giving hard code and passing it from *Java* code by param.
2. It does not show any thing even I try to show static fields in subreport.

Main method program:

```
public void generateReport() throws Exception {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("home/master.jasper");

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("home/datasource.xml");

    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource jRXmlDataSource = 
            new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource(in);
    in.close();
    InputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream("/datasource.xml");
    params.put("JR", jRXmlDataSource);
    params.put("TEXT", "test");
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, params, new JRXmlDataSource(inputStream2));

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "/home/nikhil/Desktop/test_jasper.pdf");
}
```

Master report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="20558eff-4f04-48eb-81f2-5e4936cf0bb7">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.8150000000000004"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="615"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/home/nikhil/Desktop/temp/working_jasper_with_subreport_(copy)/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="JR" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="SUB_REPORT" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[section/title]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="streetAddressLine" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/addr/streetAddressLine]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="city" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/addr/city]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="state" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/addr/state]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="postalCode" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/addr/postalCode]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="given" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/patient/name/given]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="family" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/patient/name/family]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/patient/birthTime/@value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="root" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/id/@root]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="value2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/effectiveTime/@value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/custodian/assignedCustodian/representedCustodianOrganization/name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="streetAddressLine2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/custodian/assignedCustodian/representedCustodianOrganization/addr/streetAddressLine]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="city2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/custodian/assignedCustodian/representedCustodianOrganization/addr/city]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="state2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/custodian/assignedCustodian/representedCustodianOrganization/addr/state]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="postalCode2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/custodian/assignedCustodian/representedCustodianOrganization/addr/postalCode]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="country" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/custodian/assignedCustodian/representedCustodianOrganization/addr/country]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="country2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/custodian/assignedCustodian/representedCustodianOrganization/addr/country]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="title2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/title]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="root2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/componentOf/encompassingEncounter/id/@root]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="root3" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/componentOf/encompassingEncounter/location/healthCareFacility/id/@root]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="value3" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/componentOf/encompassingEncounter/effectiveTime/low/@value]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/patient/ethnicGroupCode/@code]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="displayName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/patient/administrativeGenderCode/@displayName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="code2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component/section/code/@code]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="426" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="104" y="25" width="100" height="20" uuid="2518874d-82a6-425e-8ed3-3100a4a0f995"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{given}+" "+$F{family}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-6" y="25" width="111" height="331" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#EFEFEF" uuid="3fb001ef-64ee-49fb-ace1-2a6d13307cf8"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="25" width="91" height="20" uuid="dd58280a-7757-491b-bf15-c88db05a9587"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Patient NAME]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="45" width="91" height="20" uuid="93d62f43-0ed6-4f44-abfd-0406201910ed"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date of birth]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="104" y="45" width="100" height="20" uuid="666243a0-4a5a-47b9-bb30-40d091cb291b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="3" y="65" width="91" height="20" uuid="8e0f2a13-b126-48f9-964f-7e5e65092d75"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contact info]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="105" y="65" width="100" height="60" uuid="ba7d212c-46cf-4d26-af26-cc20d8ba2133"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{streetAddressLine}+"\n"+
$F{city}+"\n"+
$F{state}+"\n"+
$F{postalCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="6" y="125" width="549" height="1" forecolor="#E3E3E3" uuid="8667d3fa-b103-42b8-93f7-93dddc893e8f"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="146" width="91" height="20" uuid="a2ebab44-c4c4-43f0-8ce5-e62d9748da3e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Document created]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="126" width="91" height="20" uuid="db1b3c2b-09e2-4b3b-9ba8-4efe111dc997"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Document id ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="105" y="146" width="161" height="20" uuid="e17d0580-c42f-4542-b7ae-2da77923608a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="105" y="125" width="201" height="20" uuid="7a1e5892-ff28-453c-a15a-29c3eaac154f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{root}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-12" y="166" width="567" height="1" forecolor="#E3E3E3" uuid="ab1177e8-0f4d-4ac7-8480-fe4123be4ba5"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="167" width="91" height="20" uuid="90677593-392b-4542-a920-924b38dabb0e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Author]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="187" width="91" height="20" uuid="3a181bd9-28e1-4ee1-af75-1d13153364e3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contect info]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="104" y="167" width="100" height="20" uuid="05b1a78f-80d5-41d9-8ec9-b27ecc68925f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="104" y="187" width="162" height="54" uuid="738be447-33f7-4682-bac8-7dcbc838891a"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{streetAddressLine2}+
$F{city2}+"\n"+
$F{state2}+"\n"+", "+
$F{postalCode2}+", "+$F{country2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="25" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#E3E3E3" uuid="63d0e35d-74be-4227-bdd3-0ce60cfe6185"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="204" y="0" width="175" height="20" uuid="e47034d7-7e5d-4c42-886b-ed06d1e32e7f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-6" y="355" width="561" height="1" forecolor="#E3E3E3" uuid="3b1b4128-83f4-4f2e-8a1e-943bf62aed52"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="241" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#E3E3E3" uuid="2bb25090-98df-42b0-b346-04a1469891db"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="242" width="91" height="20" uuid="e6cddcaa-7e45-4ad4-ad90-e43af2acce5f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Encounter id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="262" width="91" height="20" uuid="29806d36-ea9e-4d8b-8fb7-c8dcce5f66dc"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Encounter date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="282" width="91" height="20" uuid="5ceff0b6-c88e-4cd1-a43e-049ef109525f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Encounter location]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="104" y="242" width="100" height="20" uuid="1e40c668-a382-4a2c-8701-655f4e8db73b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{root2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="104" y="262" width="100" height="20" uuid="f892ade0-1ac4-4740-ab29-67372b2557ad"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="104" y="282" width="100" height="20" uuid="debef823-e775-4675-b765-b8f3c3c007d7"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{root3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="555" y="26" width="1" height="329" forecolor="#E3E3E3" uuid="ce7605ec-8566-4604-af70-75e4bacd4330"/>
            </line>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="278" y="45" width="91" height="80" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#EFEFEF" uuid="316dd28f-6b2d-4346-95ec-2b0111821563"/>
            </rectangle>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-6" y="302" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#E3E3E3" uuid="fc7d1a55-8849-4c1c-8415-21087b8f6346"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="303" width="105" height="20" uuid="b2bc19c2-7d7e-4a26-92f9-eaf1f442ad98"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Document maintained by]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="323" width="91" height="20" uuid="e642ba94-2d55-4067-8d5e-5e08cf1532c4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contact info]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="105" y="303" width="100" height="20" uuid="7cbe395e-a084-49a7-9702-cd1115266cae"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="278" y="45" width="91" height="20" uuid="65002dbc-c01a-4dd2-9fce-0ae071f4a240"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sex]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="278" y="65" width="91" height="20" uuid="1e9c1cce-e1ce-4686-a187-3344bf0784ba"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ethinicity]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="278" y="85" width="91" height="20" uuid="a273b9bb-51dd-44fb-898e-dd35a4d753b9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Pateint id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="369" y="45" width="100" height="20" uuid="f0349cf0-2bba-4a7e-9258-033ab7846260"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{displayName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="369" y="65" width="100" height="20" uuid="c9b0f322-5a6e-4051-98d3-e057e094bc05"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="51" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="75" splitType="Stretch">
            **<subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="17" y="35" width="362" height="21" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="52f4fefc-c442-498f-bd61-aa18baa50d3f"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[new String("//home//nikhil//Desktop//temp//jasper//subreport_inpatient.jasper")]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>**
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="17" y="0" width="116" height="18" uuid="c54b82e2-a2a4-4f9b-aa63-7eacc9f1a72c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Table of contents2]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport_inpatient" pageWidth="270" pageHeight="576" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="270" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="0b236f54-4973-4661-9bca-09748e71e710">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="title1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/ClinicalDocument/component/structuredBody/component]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[section/title]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="18" y="11" width="100" height="20" uuid="d08cdcb5-1337-41d6-9792-347e69a6d5fe"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Title :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="147" y="11" width="100" height="20" uuid="98cdaa96-dced-4d00-a486-76a9fe6adf21"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```